# Chromecast memory related crash

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, chromecast, google-cast, emscripten

I have been experimenting with Chromecast (2013 and 2015 models) to try and run a small Unity3D game. Basically, display 4 sprites on the screen. The game is compiled (by Unity's tools) to WebGL using Emscripten on the backend.

One of the issues I have run into is related to the size of the Javascript file. In this case, Empscripten generates a Javascript file that is approximately 24MB. The Chromecast consistently crashes in one of several ways. The screen may flicker, it may freeze all black or all white/gray or it may result in a brain freeze screen. In some cases, it eventually reboots and in others it freezes until a power cycle.

To test the theory I generated several sizes of Javascript file and loaded them manually via the remote debugger. The generated file creates a series of variables that are each incremented by one from the prior variable for the sake of creating a large file. I can't peg a precise size but somewhere between 40,000 and 50,000 lines causes the Chromecast to crash. When I can get a successful heap snapshot it indicates a size of around 8MB. Sometimes it does not crash until taking a snapshot of the heap.

The following was used to generate the various size javascript files:

```
python -c 'numi = 41400; print("a1 = 1"); print("\n".join(["a{0} = a{1} 
+ 1".format(i+1,i) for i in range(1,numi)]));
print("document.write(a{0});".format(numi));' > l41400.js
```

I tried some small Emscripten based apps that worked just fine. Apps with large Javascript files resulted in the same behavior as the Unity game.

Calling location.reload() from the debugger console reloads the page without freeing memory. Calling it repeatedly will eventually result in the same symptoms as the large Javascript file. Ie - it will flicker, freeze or reboot.

There also appears to be a 64MB size limit for a new ArrayBuffer but at least trying to use a larger buffer resutls in an exception and not a crash.

There was a --split or --js-split option to Emscripten in the past to split the Javascript across multiple files. This was deprecated and is no longer an option. I am not sure that solution would have been feasible anyway for even larger Javascript files.

I am wondering if anybody else has seen this issue, if it is a known issue and if anyone has a work around to the Javascript file size issue?

Comment: One thing to note is that the remote debugger has a bug related to memory leak, so when you are connected through the debugger, you run into all sorts of issues in such cases. In terms of running into issues with large JS files, please open a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list and provide the information you mentioned here.

Comment: Ok. I've filed a ticket for the JS size issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=683. Can you point me to an existing issue that covers the debugger memory leak?

Comment: For the memory leak, I am aware of an internal issue that we have filed, I don't know if there is an external one or not.

Comment: One more thing to bring up, and to set the expectation, is that even if Chromecast doesn't crash when loading that JS file, the performance that you can get from that low-powered device is not going to be anything close to what users would like to see in a real game; the best approach for any game that has non-trivial logic and constructs is really using the remote display and only for trivial games an HTML solution is recommended. Can you add remote display to your game?

Comment: Thanks Ali. I understand that the Chromecast will have limited performance and potentially overheat if pushed too hard. I have no delusions of running a full 3D game that hard core gamers would want. My goal was to see how far I could go with something like Unity by keeping the game simple. I've played around with various webGL demos/games and run into issues there as well but there is a fair amount that works. I also tried Construct 2 with a couple of the simple demos and it works except for audio.

Comment: I attempted to use remote display with Unity by exporting it to Android Studio. The UnityPlayer (native code via JNI) expects to be passed an Activity and I wasn't able to coax it into using a CastPresentation. Using the full screen casting wasn't performant even for a simple game. I've assumed at this point that without direct and intentional support for Chromecast from Unity remote display can't work.

Comment: There is now a Unity plugin for Cast that you can use: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-cast-remote-display-plugin-for.html?linkId=19276940